# \leavevmode cause overlay of labels in description list

Tags: lists, description

I have a description list at the beginning of a proof environment and want the first label to begin in the same column as the remaining labels. When I put a \leavevmode before the first \item, the label for the first item overlays the label for the second item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,draft=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

% \newtheorem must follow cleveref
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\def\corollaryautorefname{Corollary}         % Needed for \autoref
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\def\definitionautorefname{Definition}       % Needed for \autoref
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\def\lemmaautorefname{Lemma}                 % Needed for \autoref

\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}
\usepackage[draft]{showlabels}
\showlabels{cite}
\showlabels{cref}
\showlabels{crefrange}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
foo
\begin{proof}
\begin{description}
\leavevmode
\item[prop1:]
proof of prop1.
\item[prop2:]
proof of prop2
\end{description}
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a latex list should only have items preceded by `\item`. `\leavevmode` is a syntax error, what is the intention?

Comment: The intent is for the first label to not begin on the same line as "Proof." A \\ is invalid either after \begin{proof} or after \begin{description}.

Comment: oh you could put it before `\begin{description}` (or `\mbox{}` is more idiomatic LaTeX than the `\leavevmode` primitive.

Comment: That works. If you care to put the information in an answer I'll upcheck it and mark it as solving the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A latex list should only have items preceded by \item. \leavevmode is a syntax error, what is the intention?

If you want a "normal" paragraph to hole the proof label before the list starts you could put `\leavevmode` (or `\mbox{}` would be better LaTeX) *before* the

```
\begin{description}
```

Not after it.

Comment: It turns out that I can also do

Comment: It turns out that I can also use "\ " after "\proof". Is that considered goog form, or is "\mbox{}" preferred?

Comment: `\mbox{}` is better `\ ` takes up horizontal space so may force a linebreak if your proof label is long